# Terminal rules for asking for password

Tags: gnome-terminal

Why does the terminal ask for a password when I run a command with sudo, even if I have already entered my password for another sudo command a while back in the same terminal.

Is there any way to change this setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a timeout limit for security reasons.  If you were working and took a break anyone coming to the terminal would have full access to the system if it didn't time out.  **The timeout is 15 minutes by default**.

You can change the default time by editing changing the configuration with `sudo visudo` and adding a `Defaults timestamp_timeout=#` setting.  The `#` is minutes.  `-1` would mean no timeout.

More details at: [RootSudo Timeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

The sudo password wont be asked again for a short time after you first use it, if you want to extend that time in which you don't have to type the password again use:

`sudo -v`

You will be asked for your password, type it as usual, and once done, you can start running all the commands you want without introducing the password again.

Comment: Do you know what that "short time" is? And is there a way to change that time? Thanks